# USB CodeMeter licence not found on dongle in Vista/7 on new ASUS Laptop, but XP is ok

Tags: windows-7, usb

Brand new ASUS K70IO laptop, clean windows install, that I try to use a USB dongle from Codemeter on, needed for running Sequoia (sound editing software) from Magix. Worked fine on XP for years, both desktops and laptops (ASUS).

For some reason the Sequoia license on the dongle is not seen by the Codemeter application when running under Vista/7, though the eventlist in CM tells me when you insert the dongle etc. In win explorer the dongle pops up as a virtual disk, as expected. The green light on the dongle is on, a sign "things are working"...

As the dongle works fine in XP...any hints on "windows services/applications" in Win7 that might cause this behaviour?

Or any local ASUS laptop behaviour on current models?

WinFirewall has been shut off, NOD32 virusprotection too, tried to "run the CM app as admin", moved around on different USBports etc etc etc.

Weeks of support communication with Magix have not helped.

BR/J

Answer (score 1):

Based on this chart:

[image: Crossplatform Compatibility]

it looks like everything was based around Windows XP. Windows 7 is not even on the compatibility list. I would contact the company that made the dongle and find out what they suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest drivers from [here](http://wibu.us/downloads/index.html) for Windows 7. You probably just need a runtime update. CodeMeter fully supports Windows 7  32 and 64-bit versions.